# Ring with spectrum homeomorphic to a given topological space

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

I would like to ask whether given a topological space $X$, we can find a commutative ring with unity $R$ such that $\operatorname{Spec} R$ (together with the Zariski topology) is homeomorphic to $X$.

Since the spectrum is a compact space, this is obviously only possible if $X$ is compact. Furthermore, from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106043/rings-whose-spectrum-is-hausdorff) we obtain that for spectra, $T_1$ already implies Hausdorff.

How many more restrictions must we impose? Can we give a characterisation of when a topological space is a spectrum of a ring?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space

Comment: Not exactly: $X$ is *quasi-*compact and *Kolmogorov* (`T0`). Melvin Hochster's dissertation for his Ph. D. at Princeton was about  this problem (1967).

Comment: @Bernard There are different terminologies. I call a space compact iff you call it quasi-compact.

Comment: Sure. I use Bourbaki's terminology.

Comment: Bourbaki books are great! And of course, in their terminology, you are quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_space which provides a pretty satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 8):

A topological space which is homeomorphic to the spectrum of a ring is called a *spectral space*.  Spectral spaces were characterized intrinsically by Melvin Hochster in his thesis:

> **Theorem (Hochster)**: Let $X$ be a topological space.  Then $X$ is spectral iff it satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - $X$ is [sober](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space).
> - $X$ is compact.
> - If $U,V\subseteq X$ are compact open sets, then $U\cap V$ is also compact.
> - The compact open subsets of $X$ form a basis for the topology of $X$.

It is not hard to show that every spectral space satisfies these conditions (note that the compact open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ are just the finite unions of distinguished open sets).  The reverse direction is much more difficult; see Theorem 6 of [this paper of Hochster's](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X/) for details.

Comment: Now both answers are correct, but I can only accept one...

Comment: In any case, I upvoted both answers.