# Are there integral domains of dimension two with exactly four primes? How do they look like?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I’m trying to think of an example for an integral domain of dimension two with exactly four prime ideals – I fail to find one. Does such a ring exist?

Furthermore, is there a local ring with this property? Is any such ring local?

Comment: Such a ring might be the coordinate ring of an affine variety of degree 4 over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$. The four primes/maximal ideals would be the points of the variety, while dimension 2 means the points live in a dimension/degree 2 extension of $\mathbb{F}_{2}$. But, in saying that, I can't immediately think of such a variety/ring.

Comment: @User0112358 Such a ring can't be noetherian, otherwise would have infinitely many primes.

Comment: @user26857 do you mean to say a Noetherian ring (integral domain?) necessarily has infinitely many primes?

Comment: @User0112358 I mean that a noetherian integral domain of dimension two has infinitely many primes.

Comment: @user26857 okay, you're right. But now I am interested in this :P Is this fact obvious?

Comment: @User0112358 Obvious not, but pretty standard; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75231/121097).

Comment: @user26857 thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know an example off the top of my head, but there is a quite general existence theorem.  Namely, if $P$ is any finite poset, then there exists a commutative ring $R$ whose poset of prime ideals is isomorphic to $P$.  So in your case, you could take $P$ to be $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with $a<b<c$ and $a<d$ (for instance).  You then get a two dimensional ring $R$ with exactly four primes and one minimal prime, and modding out the minimal prime gives a domain.  This example is not local, since it has two different maximal ideals ($c$ and $d$), but you could make it local by changing the poset so that $d<c$.

This existence theorem is a special case of an even more general theorem of Hochster characterizing the topological spaces that can be Spec of a ring.  See [Ring with spectrum homeomorphic to a given topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741965/ring-with-spectrum-homeomorphic-to-a-given-topological-space).

Comment: Actually, I was wondering about exactly this question. This is extremely helpful.