# Spectrum of Artinian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand links between Artinian property of a ring $R$ and its spectrum. I suppose that $R$ is noetherian.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106069/121097) answer is perfect, particulary: TFAE
5) $R$ is Artinian
6) $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is discrete
7) $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is finite and discrete

It is clear for me that (5) is equivalent with $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is $T_1$ i.e. points are closed so I get: (6) $\Rightarrow$ (5)

It is clear that (7) $\Rightarrow$ (6).

Any idea to conclude?

Comment: If $R$ is Artinian, all prime ideals are maximal (since an Artinian domain is a field), and there are finitely many of them (take a minimal element of the set of finite intersections of maximal ideals, then prove there are no other maximal ideals). It is then easy to see that $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is discrete.

Comment: Thanks! $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is discrete because it's a finite space builded with closed points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be artinian, with Jacobson radical $J$. Then $J$ is nilpotent and $R/J$ is product of fields. We can lift these idempotents to $R$, and hence $R$ is a finite product of local rings.

Assume therefore that $R$ is local artinian, with maximal ideal $J$. Since $J$ is nilpotent, it is contained in every prime ideal, so is the unique prime. Thus $\mathrm{Spec}\,R$ is a single point.